# ggplot2 stacked line plot acting funny

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

My stacked plot is going all wonky in the later years.  Could someone look at my code and tell me where I went wrong?  I thought my code was identical to the example code (both below).

I am not very experienced with ggplot2 plot stacking so I might be making a simple error.

I wanted something that looked like:
[image: Stacked Plot]

The code to produce that produces the above stacked plot is available as part of The R Graphics Cookbook and can be found at [Revolutions R Blog Post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/02/a-review-of-the-r-graphics-cookbook.html).
**From The R Graphics Cookbook**
     library(ggplot2)
     library(gcookbook)

```
 ggplot(uspopage, aes(x=Year, y=Thousands, fill=AgeGroup)) +
 geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4) +
 scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues", breaks=rev(levels(uspopage$AgeGroup)))
```

**I thought I had pretty much duplicated the syntax.**  But, it seems to me that I must have made a mistake somewhere.

```
 lawsize <- as.data.frame(read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EconometricsBySimulation/wild-monkey/master/usc.csv"))

 ggplot(lawsize, aes(x=Year, y=KB, fill=factor(Name)))+
 geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4)
 scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues", breaks=rev(levels(lawsize$Name)))
```

[image: My Stacked Plot]

Thanks for your consideration in this matter! F

Comment: Have you checked the data? `lawsize` contains duplicate entries. As well, most of the entries in `lawsize$Name` are lower case but not all. Try removing the duplicates (`lawsize = lawsize[!duplicated(lawsize), ]`) and changing all entries in `lawsize$Name` to lower case (`lawsize$Name = tolower(lawsize$Name)`)

Comment: Thanks! Should have known it was human error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to follow [Sandy Muspratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419994/sandy-muspratt)'s suggestions, but even then you'll have over 60 factors producing something like:

```
lawsize$Name <- factor(tolower(lawsize$Name))
lawsize = lawsize[!duplicated(lawsize), ]

gg <- ggplot(lawsize, aes(x=Year, y=KB, fill=Name))
gg <- gg + geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4)
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="none")
gg
```

[image]

which is *pretty*, but—IMO—hardly informative. Perhaps thinking more about what story you're trying to communicate before picking a visualization would be in order?